# Partition the variables into groups using function ClustOfVar::kmeansvar()

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to partition the variables from the data set 'mtcars' into groups using function `ClustOfVar::kmeansvar()`.

All of the variables in the data set are numerical, but I turned some of them into categorical in order to get a more general image of how things work. However, the function kmeansvar() throws an error:

> Some categorical variables have same names of categories,             rename categories or use the option `rename.level=TRUE` to rename it automatically.

However, that option seems to be no longer available. Of course I could go and change the names of the categories by hand, but I would like a more general solution. Anyone knows one?

```
library(ClustOfVar)
library(tidyverse)
data <- mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(vs, am, gear, carb, cyl), factor)

xqual <- data %>% select_if(is.factor) # categorical variables
xquant <- data %>% select_if(is.numeric) # numeric variables
k.means <- kmeansvar(xquant, xqual, init = 3) # k-means clustering
```